# What is wrong with my class I can't instantiate using a custom instructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Dog{
    private:
        int age;
        string name;

    public:
        Dog(int a, string x){ //constructor
            age = a;
            name = x;

        };
        string getName(){
            return name;
        };
        int getAge(){

            return age;
        };


};


int main(){

    Dog(10, "fid0") ben;

    cout<< ben.getName();

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with my class I can't instantiate using a custom instructor? I am still new to cpp and cannot figure out why. I have not been able to figure out why sometimes my Dog object is seen as a pointer at times. Resources would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need `Dog ben(10, "fido");`

Comment: You got the syntax wrong. `Dog(10, "fid0") ben;` --> `Dog ben(10, "fid0");`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Dog(10, "fid0") ben;
```

to:

```
Dog ben(10, "fid0");
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Whenever I add return this.age, I get an error asking stating that dog is a pointer. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so you need `this->age`

Comment: Or `return (*this).age;`, or just `return age;`.

Comment: is it bad practice to use this when constructing a class? I was taught to use it in java